# Сallback (анонимные) функции (использовать array_filter или array_map)

Tags: php, массивы, функции, callback

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу. Я ее решил, но каким то ужасным костылем, с неправильным применением Сallback функции.

Вот такая задача:
Сallback (анонимные) функции
Для всех заданий:

- использовать array_filter или array_map;
- на входе для всех заданий, дан массив:

  ```
  [ 

      ['name' => 'Yan', 'salery' => '1200', 'work_hours' => 180], 

      ['name' => 'Barda', 'salery' => '2150', 'work_hours' => 160], 

      ['name' => 'Piter', 'salery' => '1500', 'work_hours' => 160], 

      ['name' => 'Alex', 'salery' => '3340', 'work_hours' => 167], 

      ['name' => 'Deiv', 'salery' => '1700', 'work_hours' => 176], 

      ['name' => 'Bob', 'salery' => '1150', 'work_hours' => 182], 

      ['name' => 'Claus', 'salery' => '2810', 'work_hours' => 155], 

      ['name' => 'Lina', 'salery' => '1600', 'work_hours' => 169], 

      ['name' => 'Rod', 'salery' => '2780', 'work_hours' => 191], 

      ['name' => 'Kristy', 'salery' => '2180', 'work_hours' => 144], 

      ['name' => 'Ron', 'salery' => '1670', 'work_hours' => 157], 

   ]
  ```

  - выводить результирующий массив в табличном виде для каждого задания.

1) Всем сотрудникам у кого ЗП меньше 1600 добавить 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = [
    ['name' => 'Yan', 'salary' => '1200', 'work_hours' => 180],
    ['name' => 'Barda', 'salary' => '2150', 'work_hours' => 160],
    ['name' => 'Piter', 'salary' => '1500', 'work_hours' => 160],
    ['name' => 'Alex', 'salary' => '3340', 'work_hours' => 167],
    ['name' => 'Deiv', 'salary' => '1700', 'work_hours' => 176],
    ['name' => 'Bob', 'salary' => '1150', 'work_hours' => 182],
    ['name' => 'Claus', 'salary' => '2810', 'work_hours' => 155],
    ['name' => 'Lina', 'salary' => '1600', 'work_hours' => 169],
    ['name' => 'Rod', 'salary' => '2780', 'work_hours' => 191],
    ['name' => 'Kristy', 'salary' => '2180', 'work_hours' => 144],
    ['name' => 'Ron', 'salary' => '1670', 'work_hours' => 157],
];

$data = array_map(function ($worker) {
    $worker['salary'] = $worker['salary'] < 1600
        ? $worker['salary'] + 100
        : $worker['salary'];
    return $worker;
}, $data);

?>

<table border="1" style="text-align: center;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px">
            <b>Name</b>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px">
            <b>Salary</b>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px">
            <b>Work hours</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <? foreach ($data as $worker): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?= $worker['name'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $worker['salary'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $worker['work_hours'] ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <? endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Супер!!! Это то что надо!!! А подскажите, что означает = $worker (равно). Еще зеленый, не все понимаю )

Comment: я понял, это тоже самое что <?php echo

Comment: Тернарный оператор, поищите информацию по этому поводу. <?= $var ?> эквивалентно <?php echo $var; ?>

Comment: да, понял. Спасибо!